# In kibana(5.1.1) in Data Table visualization how can I Use aggregate function like `(sum/count)` for whole bucket?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana-5

I want print `sum(duration)/3600` using Data Table visualization for  whole bucket how can achieve the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid it isn't possible to do calculations based on counts in *Kibana*. If you were looking at the *sum* or *average* or some other similar operation, you could probably fake it in your data with scripted fields, but counts are absolute.

You may be able to do what you need, using [Timelion](https://www.elastic.co/blog/timelion-timeline) though. The catch there is that Timelion doesn't yet support **terms aggs**. But still you could give it a try using the **Json Input** [filter](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/calling-groovy-script-from-kibana/2542/4).

Hope it helps!

Comment: I want to calculate `sum(Duration)/3600` will it be possible using data table visualization?

Comment: As far as I know, it's a big **no** unless you write a custom [plugin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29174113/how-can-i-do-scripted-aggregation-in-kibana-elasticsearch?) to achieve it.

Comment: Do you know any website for reference to develop custom plugin